# convert let into lambda in scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, let, named, letrec

this is the original form:

```scm
(define (split-by l p k)
  (let loop ((low '())
             (high '())
             (l l))
    (cond ((null? l)
           (k low high))
          ((p (car l))
           (loop low (cons (car l) high) (cdr l)))
          (else
           (loop (cons (car l) low) high (cdr l))))))
```

and i'm trying to convert let, this is what I have tried:

```scm
(define (split-by l p k)
  (lambda (loop)     
    (cond ((null? l) (k low high))
          ((p (car l)) 
           (loop low (cons (car l) high) (cdr l)))
          (else
           (loop (cons (car l) low) high (cdr l))
           ((low '()) (high '()) (l l))))))
```

I don't know how to fix this so if anyone could help what I am doing wrong would be a great help.

Comment: I believe you're thinking of the conversion of `(let ((x E1)) E2)` into `((lambda (x) E2) E1)`. That conversion doesn't apply to the "named let".

Comment: you fix this with ***`fix`***. :)

Comment: @molbdnilo [You can convert a named `let` into a `rec`+`lambda`](http://qr.ae/RUymgf), but `rec` still uses `letrec` behind the scenes. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're doing, `p` is a predicate and you split the list `l` according to this, aggregating your two resulting lists with the aggregation function `k`; in pseudo-code:

```
(split-by l p k) => (k {x in l | !p(x)} {x in l | p(x)})
```

The problem when replacing your `let` is that the `loop` function is recursively defined. It is of the form:

```
(define (loop low high lst)
    (cond
        ((null? lst) <some value>)
        (<some predicate> (loop (cons (car lst) low) high (cdr lst)))
        (else (loop low (cons (car lst) high) (cdr lst)))))
```

You absolutely can use this directly in your function, defining the 'inner' recursive part, but this cannot be made using simple `lambda` without `let`: the function needs to *refer to itself* (since it is recursive), and you can only do that by assigning it a name. `define` will do that, `let` will let you do that, but no matter how you turn it, you need that self-reference. If you're clever and pass in a continuation:

```
(lambda (low high lst cont)
    (cond
        ((null? lst) (agg high lst))
        ((pred? (car lst)) (cont low (cons (car lst) high) (cdr lst) cont))
        (else (cont (cons (car lst) low) high (cdr lst) cont))))
```

You've removed that self-reference by making it explicit, but what do you pass as `cont` ? Well, if you assigned that via a let, you have a symbol refering to it:

```
(define (split-by2 lst pred? agg)
    (let ((f (lambda (low high lst cont)
                (cond
                    ((null? lst) (agg low high))
                    ((pred? (car lst)) (cont low (cons (car lst) high) (cdr lst) cont))
                    (else (cont (cons (car lst) low) high (cdr lst) cont))))))
        (f '() '() lst f)))
```

Or more concisely with a `define`, which does the exact same thing (without the need to pass in the continuation):

```
(define (split-by3 lst pred? agg)
    (define (f low high lst)
        (cond
            ((null? lst) (agg low high))
            ((pred? (car lst)) (f low (cons (car lst) high) (cdr lst)))
            (else (f (cons (car lst) low) high (cdr lst)))))
    (f '() '() lst))
```

All of them operate similarly:

```
(split-by '(1 2 3 4) (lambda (x) (> x 2)) list)
=> ((2 1) (4 3))   
(split-by2 '(1 2 3 4) (lambda (x) (> x 2)) list)
=> ((2 1) (4 3))   
(split-by3 '(1 2 3 4) (lambda (x) (> x 2)) list)
=> ((2 1) (4 3))
```

But you cannot get away with defining a *symbol* for your recursive function*.

As to why your example didn't work, it's working perfectly fine, except that it creates a *function*, taking as argument a *function* (which I called `cont` above) and applying your logic *given that function `loop`*. Since you then don't have any 'loop' to pass it (as you haven't bound it), it returns that function and proceeds to do nothing (in addition, in your returned `lambda`, `low` and `high` are not defined).

* This is not entirely true as you *could* do it using [combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus) on your lambda, but that would make it *much* more complex than it ought to:

```
(define Y
  (lambda (h)
    ((lambda (x) (x x))
     (lambda (g)
       (h (lambda args (apply (g g) args)))))))

(define (split-ycomb lst pred? agg)
    ((Y 
        (lambda(f)
            (lambda (low high l)
                (cond
                    ((null? l) (agg low high))
                    ((pred? (car l)) (f low (cons (car l) high) (cdr l)))
                    (else (f (cons (car l) low) high (cdr l)))))))
    '() '() lst))
```

Or for an even <s>uglier</s> purer version, with an inline combinator:

```
(define (split-ycomb2 lst pred? agg)
    (((lambda (h)
        ((lambda (x) (x x))
            (lambda (g)
                (h (lambda args (apply (g g) args)))))) 
        (lambda(f)
            (lambda (low high l)
                (cond
                    ((null? l) (agg low high))
                    ((pred? (car l)) (f low (cons (car l) high) (cdr l)))
                    (else (f (cons (car l) low) high (cdr l)))))))
    '() '() lst))
```

Which work as expected (thanks to the layers of lambdas):

```
(split-ycomb '(1 2 3 4) (lambda (x) (> x 2)) list)
=> ((2 1) (4 3))
(split-ycomb2 '(1 2 3 4) (lambda (x) (> x 2)) list)
=> ((2 1) (4 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try writing

```
(define (split-by l p k)  
  (let ((loop 
          (lambda (low high l)
             (cond 
               ((null? l)
                  (k low high))
               ((p (car l))
                  (loop low (cons (car l) high) (cdr l)))
               (else
                  (loop (cons (car l) low) high (cdr l)))))))
    (loop '() '() l)))
```

but the trouble is that the `lambda`'s body can't refer to the `loop` name yet, *as it is being* defined (you could just replace `let` with [`letrec`](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/The%20R5RS%20standard#binding-constructs), and then it'd work, but that's not what you're asking here).

The name `loop` being defined by `let` is *not in scope* inside the init expression for it. That is the meaning of `let` being non-recursive. Its recursive variant, `letrec`, does provide for the name being defined, to be *in  scope* inside the init-expression (just that its value isn't allowed to be queried when the init-value is calculated).

There's a simple trick though (a kind of poor man's [Y combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator)), which emulates true self-reference through *replication*, which is achieved by *self-application*, as in

```
(define (split-by l p k)  
  (let ((foo 
          (lambda (loop low high l)
             (cond 
               ((null? l)
                  (k low high))
               ((p (car l))
                  (loop loop low (cons (car l) high) (cdr l)))
               (else
                  (loop loop (cons (car l) low) high (cdr l)))))))
    (foo foo '() '() l)))
```

and all's right again under the sun, i.e. the non-recursive `let` -- the `loop` name being referred to inside the lambda body, is just a lambda parameter now, thus *in scope*.

And since the `let` is plain, non-recursive, it is easy to re-write this with a simple `lambda`-application, as

```
(define (split-by l p k)  
  ((lambda (foo) (foo foo '() '() l))   ; (lambda (loop ...
   (lambda (loop low high l)            ;   is duplicated into the two foos
             (cond 
               ((null? l)
                  (k low high))
               ((p (car l))
                  (loop loop low (cons (car l) high) (cdr l)))
               (else
                  (loop loop (cons (car l) low) high (cdr l)))))))
```